# jquery remove breaks markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have such code:

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <div id="t1" style="position:relative; top:100; left:100;"></div>
    <div id="t2" style="position:relative; top:200; left:200;"></div>
</div>

<script>
$(function () {
    $('#t1').remove();
);
</script>
```

after that script div-t2 is moving randomly to another place, and if i remove t2, then t1 moves. how to make their position stable, i dont want them to travel on my screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give them (the inner divs) `style="position:absolute"`.

Answer (score 2):

change `position: relative` to `position: absolute` (relative to the parent) or `position: fixed` (relative to the document)

Comment: Mister G, you entered the solution exact the same moment i did - respect :)

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute positioning

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <div id="t1" style="position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px;"></div>
    <div id="t2" style="position:absolute; top:200px; left:200px;"></div>
</div>
```

and also add a unit to your position values (*i have added **px***)

Answer (score 1):

The positions of `t1` and `t2` are relative to where they would be in the normal run of HTML rendering.

To achieve what you want, make the `position` of `t1` and `t2` `absolute`.